# javascript event listener function

Tags: javascript

I am working with a form for my class and the point of the form is that when we click a radio button (option button) with main campus or north it populates information within the form utilizing javascript.

My issue that I am having is that I have two event listeners one utilizing my function for the main campus click and one for the north. However when you click on any radio button is only populates information from the function that is north. I will include the code below.

If you want to replicate my issue just take the code and click the radio buttons and see how the information does not change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>T.A.S.K. Pet Products</title>
        <!-- 
         Author:  YOUR NAME 
        -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="projectm.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>T.A.S.K. Pet Products by YOUR NAME</h1>
        <article id="contentstart">
            <h2>Customer Information</h2>
                <form action="results.html">
                    <fieldset class="name-info">
                        <label for="fnameinput">
                            First name
                            <input type="text" id="fnameinput" name="fnameinput">
                        </label>
                        <label for="lnameinput">
                            Last name
                            <input type="text" id="lnameinput" name="lnameinput">
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="address-options">
                        <legend>Please select default T.A.S.K. location.</legend>
                        <div class="two-column">
                            <input type="radio" id="main" name="taskaddress">
                            <label for="main">Main Location</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="two-column">
                            <input type="radio" id="north" name="taskaddress">
                           <label for="north">North Location</label>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="contact-info">
                        <label for="streetinput">
                            Street Address
                            <input type="text" id="streetinput" name="streetinput">
                        </label>
                        <label for="cityinput">
                            City
                            <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="cityinput">
                        </label>
                        <label for="stateinput">
                            State
                            <input type="text" id="stateinput" name="stateinput">
                        </label>
                        <label for="zipinput">
                            Zip
                        <input type="text" id="zipinput" name="zipinput">
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="submitbutton">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </article>
            <aside>
                 <h3>What&rsquo;s New for your Pet</h3>
                 <img src="images/pets.jpg">
                 <p>Sponge chew toys</p>
                 <p>Special Leashes</p>
                 <p>Glow Collars</p>
                 <p>Diet Food</p>
                 <p>Veggie Treats</p>
                 <p>Cushy Beds </p>
                 <p>Grooming Brushes</p>
                 <p>Bowls and Dishes</p>
            </aside>
            <footer>
                 <p>Helping you help you pets &bull; (623) 555-4321</p>
            </footer>
        </div>  
        <script src="projectm.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


html {
   font-size: 20px;
}
a, article, body, div, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, header, h1, 
h2, h3, img, input, label, legend, li, nav, p, section, textarea, ul {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
   padding-left: 2em;
}

/* body and page container */
body {
   font-family: "Alegreya Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
 /*  background-color: #a17f43; */
   max-width: 1000px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: auto;
   border: 2px solid olive;
   border-radius: 15px;
   background: rgb(140,198,63);
}

h1, h2, h3, p {
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
} 

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 1.6em;
   padding: 1%;
}

h2 {
   font-size: 1.2em;
   padding-bottom: 2%;
}
h3 {
   padding-bottom: 2%;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-style: italic;
   text-align: center;
}

/* main content */
article {
   width: 62%;
   padding-left: 1.4em;
   padding-top: 2%;
   float: left;
   background-color: #ffff99;
}

/* sidebar */
aside {
   padding: 2%;
   width: 31%;
   float: right;
   background-color: #c8f098;
}
aside p {
   padding-left: 2em;
}

/* form styles */
form {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.two-column {
   width: 46%;
   padding: 2%;
   float: left;
}
.two-column label {
   margin-left: 1em;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.two-column p:first-of-type {
   padding-top: 0.6em;
}

/* fieldset styles */
fieldset {
   padding: 0 2% 1em;
}
legend {
   font-size: 1.2em;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.submitbutton {
   text-align: center;
   display: none;
}
.show {
   display: block;
}

/* field styles */
input {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   margin-bottom: 0.2em;
   padding: 0.1em;
   font-size: 1em;
}
.contact-info input {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 8em;
}
#lnameinput, #streetinput { width: 15em; }
#fnameinput, #cityinput { width: 10em; }
#stateinput { width: 2em; }
#zipinput { width: 5em; }
#signup {
   padding: 0.2em;
   border: 3px solid black;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background-color: rgb(246,224,65);
}
#submit {
   padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
   margin: 0;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1em;
   background-color: rgb(170,189,126);
   border-radius: 10px;
}

/* label styles */
label {
   padding-top: 0.2em;
   font-size: 1.1em;
}
.name-info label {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}
.contact-info label {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

/* footer section */
footer {
   padding: 0.6em;
   background-color: black;
   color: floralwhite;
   text-align: center;
   clear: both;
}
footer p {
   margin: 0.4em;
}

var mainOption = document.querySelector("#main");
var northOption = document.querySelector("#north");
var streetInput = document.querySelector("#streetinput");
var cityInput = document.querySelector("#cityinput");
var stateInput = document.querySelector("#stateinput");
var zipInput = document.querySelector("#zipinput");
var submitButton = document.querySelector(".submitbutton");


var form = document.querySelector("form");

var submitButton = document.querySelector(".submitbutton");



/* selectMain function - populates form fields with Main address information */

function selectMain() {
        streetInput.value = "6000 W Olive Ave";
        cityInput.value = "Glendale";
        stateInput.value = "AZ";
        zipInput.value = "85302";

        if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
            submitButton.className = "submitbutton show";
        }

}





/* selectNorth function - populate form fields with North address information */


function selectNorth () {
    streetInput.value = "5727 West Happy Valley Road";
    cityInput.value = "Phoenix";
    stateInput.value = "AZ";
    zipInput.value = "85310";

    if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
            submitButton.className = "submitbutton show";
        }


}


/* Create event listeners for button clicks */

form.addEventListener("click", selectMain, false);
form.addEventListener("click", selectNorth, false);
```

Comment: don't want to read all that stuff, or even scroll through it. Can you please reduce the code to the relevant parts.

Comment: you don't have to read the code thomas I am just providing it so you can replicate what I see generally all you really need to look at is my javascript code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were assigning the `click` listener to your entire `form` tag, that's why it didn't matter where you were clicking, it was always assigning the new content on the inputs with those in your `selectNorth()` function, that was the last `addEventListener` assigned to it, try with:

```
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener("click", selectMain, false);
document.getElementById('north').addEventListener("click", selectNorth, false);
```

See:

```js
  let mainOption = document.querySelector("#main"),
    northOption   = document.querySelector("#north"),
    streetInput   = document.querySelector("#streetinput"),
    cityInput     = document.querySelector("#cityinput"),
    stateInput    = document.querySelector("#stateinput"),
    zipInput      = document.querySelector("#zipinput"),
    submitButton  = document.querySelector(".submitbutton"),
    form          = document.querySelector("form");

  /* selectMain function - populates form fields with Main address information */
  function selectMain() {
    streetInput.value = '6000 W Olive Ave';
    cityInput.value   = 'Glendale';
    stateInput.value  = 'AZ';
    zipInput.value    = '85302';
    if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
      submitButton.className = 'submitbutton show';
    }    
  }

  /* selectNorth function - populate form fields with North address information */
  function selectNorth () {
    streetInput.value = '5727 West Happy Valley Road';
    cityInput.value   = 'Phoenix';
    stateInput.value  = 'AZ';
    zipInput.value    = '85310';
    if (form.checkValidity() === true) {
      submitButton.className = 'submitbutton show';
    }    
  }

  /* Create event listeners for button clicks */
  document.getElementById('main').addEventListener( 'click', selectMain, false);
  document.getElementById('north').addEventListener('click', selectNorth, false);
```

```css
html {
       font-size: 20px;
    }
    a, article, body, div, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, header, h1, 
    h2, h3, img, input, label, legend, li, nav, p, section, textarea, ul {
       border: 0;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
    }
    img {
       max-width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       width: auto;
       padding-left: 2em;
    }

    /* body and page container */
    body {
       font-family: "Alegreya Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    .container {
     /*  background-color: #a17f43; */
       max-width: 1000px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       overflow: auto;
       border: 2px solid olive;
       border-radius: 15px;
       background: rgb(140,198,63);
    }

    h1, h2, h3, p {
       font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    } 

    h1 {
       text-align: center;
       font-size: 1.6em;
       padding: 1%;
    }

    h2 {
       font-size: 1.2em;
       padding-bottom: 2%;
    }
    h3 {
       padding-bottom: 2%;
       font-size: 1em;
       font-style: italic;
       text-align: center;
    }

    /* main content */
    article {
       width: 62%;
       padding-left: 1.4em;
       padding-top: 2%;
       float: left;
       background-color: #ffff99;
    }

    /* sidebar */
    aside {
       padding: 2%;
       width: 31%;
       float: right;
       background-color: #c8f098;
    }
    aside p {
       padding-left: 2em;
    }

    /* form styles */
    form {
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .two-column {
       width: 46%;
       padding: 2%;
       float: left;
    }
    .two-column label {
       margin-left: 1em;
       font-weight: bold;
    }
    .two-column p:first-of-type {
       padding-top: 0.6em;
    }

    /* fieldset styles */
    fieldset {
       padding: 0 2% 1em;
    }
    legend {
       font-size: 1.2em;
       font-weight: bold;
    }
    .submitbutton {
       text-align: center;
       display: none;
    }
    .show {
       display: block;
    }

    /* field styles */
    input {
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       margin-bottom: 0.2em;
       padding: 0.1em;
       font-size: 1em;
    }
    .contact-info input {
       display: inline-block;
       position: absolute;
       left: 8em;
    }
    #lnameinput, #streetinput { width: 15em; }
    #fnameinput, #cityinput { width: 10em; }
    #stateinput { width: 2em; }
    #zipinput { width: 5em; }
    #signup {
       padding: 0.2em;
       border: 3px solid black;
       font-size: 1.2em;
       border-radius: 10px;
       background-color: rgb(246,224,65);
    }
    #submit {
       padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
       margin: 0;
       display: inline-block;
       font-size: 1em;
       background-color: rgb(170,189,126);
       border-radius: 10px;
    }

    /* label styles */
    label {
       padding-top: 0.2em;
       font-size: 1.1em;
    }
    .name-info label {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       margin-bottom: 0.4em;
    }
    .contact-info label {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       margin-bottom: 0.4em;
    }

    /* footer section */
    footer {
       padding: 0.6em;
       background-color: black;
       color: floralwhite;
       text-align: center;
       clear: both;
    }
    footer p {
       margin: 0.4em;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>T.A.S.K. Pet Products by YOUR NAME</h1>
  <article id="contentstart">
    <h2>Customer Information</h2>
    <form action="results.html">
      <fieldset class="name-info">
        <label for="fnameinput">
        First name
        <input type="text" id="fnameinput" name="fnameinput">
        </label>
        <label for="lnameinput">
        Last name
        <input type="text" id="lnameinput" name="lnameinput">
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="address-options">
        <legend>Please select default T.A.S.K. location.</legend>
        <div class="two-column">
          <input type="radio" id="main" name="taskaddress">
          <label for="main">Main Location</label>
        </div>
        <div class="two-column">
          <input type="radio" id="north" name="taskaddress">
          <label for="north">North Location</label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="contact-info">
        <label for="streetinput">
        Street Address
        <input type="text" id="streetinput" name="streetinput">
        </label>
        <label for="cityinput">
        City
        <input type="text" id="cityinput" name="cityinput">
        </label>
        <label for="stateinput">
        State
        <input type="text" id="stateinput" name="stateinput">
        </label>
        <label for="zipinput">
        Zip
        <input type="text" id="zipinput" name="zipinput">
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="submitbutton">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h3>What&rsquo;s New for your Pet</h3>
    <img src="#">
    <p>Sponge chew toys</p>
    <p>Special Leashes</p>
    <p>Glow Collars</p>
    <p>Diet Food</p>
    <p>Veggie Treats</p>
    <p>Cushy Beds </p>
    <p>Grooming Brushes</p>
    <p>Bowls and Dishes</p>
  </aside>
  <footer>
    <p>Helping you help you pets &bull; (623) 555-4321</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Sebastian you were correct it worked! I am actually surprised I didn't think if using the document.getElementById method. I am following the book and it said to use form but what you said makes absolute sense since I am targeting the entire form.

Comment: Always there are some "erratas", don't be afraid to ask if that doesn't work.